# Passing fetchedResultsController object to child returns nil later

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have a `UITableView` for my iPad app which when you tap on a row, will display a popOver with another table in it with one section. The popOver table section header is dependant on values from the `fetchedResultsController` on the main UITableView controller. When the popover first loads the information is correct. However, after the user taps on a cell in the popover, it goes to another view inside the popover that will allow you to edit data. Once you save, I call a delegate method to refresh the main `UITableView` while the popover stays shown. Then the view where the user edited the data is dismissed so it goes back to the popover `UITableView`. At this point the `fetchedResultsController` that was passed in as `slot` is now nil. I cannot figure out why it is doing this.

Why is the `slot` now nil in `SlotViewController` and how do I prevent it?

**@interface**

```
NSFetchedResultsController *fetchedResultsController;
```

**Main UITableView**

```
@synthesize fetchResultsController = _fetchedResultsController;

- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController {
    /*
     Set up the fetched results controller.
     */
    if (_fetchedResultsController != nil) {
        NSLog(@"RETURNING FETCHEDRESULTS");
        return _fetchedResultsController;
    }
    NSLog(@"Should only be called once");
    // Create the fetch request for the entity.
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    // Edit the entity name as appropriate.
    NSEntityDescription *entity = nil;
    if ([[dataObj.client objectForKey:@"appt_method"] integerValue] == 2) {
        entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Slots" inManagedObjectContext:[[CoreDataHelper sharedInstance] managedObjectContext]];
    } else {
        entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Appointments" inManagedObjectContext:[[CoreDataHelper sharedInstance] managedObjectContext]];
    }
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
    [fetchRequest setPredicate:nil];
    //[fetchRequest setIncludesPendingChanges:YES];

    // Set the batch size to a suitable number.
    //[fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];

    // Sort using the date / then time property.
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptorDate = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"date" ascending:YES];
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptorTime = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"start_time" ascending:YES selector:@selector(localizedStandardCompare:)];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptorDate, sortDescriptorTime, nil];


    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

    // Use the sectionIdentifier property to group into sections.
    NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:[[CoreDataHelper sharedInstance] managedObjectContext] sectionNameKeyPath:@"date" cacheName:nil];
//    aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
    self.fetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController;
    _fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;

    return _fetchedResultsController;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    Slots *selectedSlot = [_fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    SlotViewController *slotView = [parentNav.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SlotViewController"];
            [slotView setSlot:selectedSlot];
    CGRect rect = [self rectForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
                rect.size.width = rect.size.width / 3;
                UINavigationController *navBar = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:slotView];
                popOver = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:navBar];
                popOver.delegate = self;
                //[popOver setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 460) animated:YES];
                [popOver presentPopoverFromRect:rect inView:self permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
}
```

**SlotViewController / popover UITableView**

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSLog(@"slot: %@", _slot.date);
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyyMMdd"];
    NSDate *currDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:_slot.date];

    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"h:mma"];
    [dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"]];
    NSDate *midnight = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:0];
    NSDate *startTimeDate = [midnight dateByAddingTimeInterval:[_slot.start_time integerValue] * 60];
    NSDate *endTimeDate = [midnight dateByAddingTimeInterval:[_slot.end_time integerValue] * 60];

    NSString *startTime = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:startTimeDate];
    NSString *endTime = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:endTimeDate];

    dateFormatter.locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"E, MMM dd, yyyy"];
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@-%@",[dateFormatter stringFromDate:currDate], startTime, endTime];
}
```

I'm able to get it working properly by changing the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` code from

```
Slots *selectedSlot = [_fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

to

```
Slots *selectedSlot = [Slots disconnectedEntity];
Slots *tmpSlot = [_fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
for (id key in tmpSlot.entity.attributesByName) {
    [selectedSlot setValue:[tmpSlot valueForKey:key] forKey:key];
}
```

**disconnectedEntity**
is a Core Data managed context that is not tied to an object.

```
+ (id)disconnectedEntity {
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [[CoreDataHelper sharedInstance] managedObjectContext];
    NSEntityDescription *entityDescription = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Slots" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    return [[self alloc] initWithEntity:entityDescription insertIntoManagedObjectContext:nil];
}
```

However I am wondering why the original code will not work. I am assuming that it is because the `fetchedResultsController` is passing the reference to `selectedSlots` so when `fetchedResultsController` updates, the reference no longer exists?

Comment: Please post your interface file that includes where you define the property for your FetchedResultsController.

Comment: WHen you say you're able to get it working properly, you mean that when you iterate through the attributes before returning from the popover the fetchedResultsController is non-nil?  SlotViewController itself is continuing to exist through all of this, and hosting the Popover controller as a child?

Comment: @RobReuss that is correct. SlotViewController is open, then does a pushViewController to detailView then the SlotViewControllerDelegate will pop the view back to SlotViewController. The iteration through the attributes is actually done in the main list view.

Comment: Seems like what is making the different is getting the reference to selectedSlot from [Slots disconnectedEntity] - not clear what that is doing from the code sample.

Comment: @RobReuss see updated OP